# Claiming forced insurance in Islam

Tags: sharia, insurance

How far is it permissible or impermissible in Islam to claim costs for damages to a vehicle through insurance?

Actually there are a few governments that make vehicle insurance mandatory, in which case it is something unavoidable, but how much is it in Taqwa to claim for that after one is forced to have insurance.

Jazakallah Khair.